YAML validation using JSON schema in C or Fortran program
I have a Fortran program that uses bind(c) and some wrappers written in C to use libyaml to read/parse a YAML file at runtime.  This part of the program is a combination of Fortran and C code.
Typically we validate our YAML before running the program using python, but there is no validation in the actual compiled program.  Because it's possible to pass in a YAML that does not follow the schema but is valid YAML, the program can hang.  Is there a way to validate the YAML in Fortran or C using the jsonschema?

Have you tried searching for "c validate jsonschema"? I believe there are several libraries that provide this functionality.

The list of available implementations are found  on the JSON Schema page.
Doesn't appear to be any available for Fortran or C.

My approach would be to have one thing that parses the YAML, then translate that model to a JSON model and use one of the validators listed on the tooling page Jeremy mentioned.
YAML is mostly compatible with the JSON object model, so the translation shouldn't be a problem.
